# Split comma separated list with line number using awk and bash

Tags: shell, awk

I have a (very big) csv-file with following format:

```
id;surname;firstname;aliases
1;Simpson;Homer;Homer Jay Simpson,Homer J. Simpson
2;Simpson;Bart;Bartholomew JoJo Simpson,Bartholomew Simpson
3;Krusty the Clown;;Herschel Shmoikel Pinchas Yerucham Krustofsky
4;Simpson;Lisa;
```

Now I want to transform that into following format:

```
id;name
1;Homer Simpson
1_1;Homer Jay Simpson
1_2;Homer J. Simpson
2;Bart Simpson
2_1;Bartholomew JoJo Simpson
2_2;Bartholomew Simpson
3;Krusty the Clown
3_1;Herschel Shmoikel Pinchas Yerucham Krustofsky
4;Lisa Simpson
```

For performance reasons I would like to do that with `awk` or another UNIX-command line tool.

With `awk -F ';' '{print $1, $3, $2}'` I can separate the semicolon separated line. But how do I use `awk` in `awk` for splitting the comma separated entry again?

Comment: You've included a case with surname but no firstname (Krusty the Clown), if you can have the opposite then you should include that in your example too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
NR==1 {
    print $1, "name"
    next
}
{
    name = $3 " " $2
    gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",name)
    print $1, name
    n = split($NF,aliases,/,/)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        print $1 "_" i, aliases[i]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
id;name
1;Homer Simpson
1_1;Homer Jay Simpson
1_2;Homer J. Simpson
2;Bart Simpson
2_1;Bartholomew JoJo Simpson
2_2;Bartholomew Simpson
3;Krusty the Clown
3_1;Herschel Shmoikel Pinchas Yerucham Krustofsky
4;Lisa Simpson
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following (written and tested with shown samples).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="[;,]"
  OFS=";"
  print "id;name"
}
FNR>1{
  j=$2~/ /?2:3
  for(i=j;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i==""){
      continue
    }
    if(i==j){
      print $1,$3" "$2
    }
    else{
      print $1"_"++c,$i
    }
  }
  c=""
}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
id;name
1;Homer Simpson
1_1;Homer Jay Simpson
1_2;Homer J. Simpson
2;Bart Simpson
2_1;Bartholomew JoJo Simpson
2_2;Bartholomew Simpson
3; Krusty the Clown
3_1;Herschel Shmoikel Pinchas Yerucham Krustofsky
4;Lisa Simpson
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code here.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                       ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS="[;,]"                  ##Setting field as either semi-colon OR comma for all lines.
  OFS=";"                    ##Setting output field separator semi-colon.
  print "id;name"            ##Printing id;name string before reading Input_file.
}                            ##Closing BLOCK for BEGIN block of this awk program here.
FNR>1{                       ##Checking condition if FNR>1 then do following.
  j=$2~/ /?2:3
  for(i=j;i<=NF;i++){        ##Running a for loop from i=j to till number of fields of line.
    if($i==""){              ##Checking condition if current field value is NULL then do following.
      continue               ##Using continue to take cursor to for loop again here.
    }
    if(i==j){                ##Checking condition if i==3 then do following.
      print $1,$3" "$2       ##Printing first, 3rd,space and 2nd field of line here.
    }
    else{                    ##If above if condition is false then come to this else here.
      print $1"_"++c,$i      ##Printing first field underscore variable c value, value of current field here.
    }
  }
  c=""                       ##Nullifying variable c here.
}
'  Input_file                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Krusty the Clown is missing; is that a bug?

Comment: @tripleee, Thank you sir, I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Awk has a `split` function which lets you split strings into arrays.

```sh
awk -F ';' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS }
  { print $1, $3 " " $2
    n = split($4, alias, /,/)
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
      print $1 "_" i, alias[i] }' file.csv
```

The return value from `split` tells you how many members there are in the result array.

Comment: Try `($3 ? $3 " " : "")` if you want to get rid of the space before Krusty.

Answer (score 0):

This will do as you intend in Python 3. Notice that I typed it quickly so many improvements can be done. I believe it might be faster than awk, but I might be wrong. You can test if so using *time* command in Linux and Mac.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import csv
csvr = csv.reader(open('simpsons.csv'), delimiter = ";")

index=0
for row in csvr:
    if index == 0:
        index = index +1
        continue
    print("{};{} {}".format(index,row[2],row[1]))
    sindex=0
    for sitem in row[3].split(','):
        if sitem != "" :
            sindex = sindex + 1
            print("{};{}".format(row[0] + "_" + str(sindex),sitem))
    index = index +1
```

Hope it helps!

### Edit :

I generated a dummy list of 500k rows and tested some of the answers given by users here and it does not seem to be any important difference between Python 3 and awk. ( At least in my poor implementation in Python 3).

```
 $ time awk -f tst.awk fivehundredthousand.txt &> /dev/null

real    0m2.141s
user    0m2.118s
sys     0m0.020s

 $ time ./handle_csv.py >/dev/null

real    0m1.750s
user    0m1.722s
sys     0m0.021s

$ time awk -f ravinder.awk fivehundredthousand.txt &> /dev/null

real    0m1.736s
user    0m1.718s
sys     0m0.017s
```

Comment: For your timing results - was that third-run timing of each script to eliminate the effects of cache-ing?

Comment: @EdMorton I actually ran each one only once. Is there a cache in this context?

Comment: Yes, subsequent runs can be faster than initial runs due to cache-ing so you must always run any command 3 times before taking that 3rd execution timing for comparison with the timing of any other command (which you'd also run 3 times).

Comment: Awesome. I did not know there was a process level cache-ing. Is it related to the CPU cache? Do you have any link related to this?

Comment: Idk what it's related to and I was just googling for a reference but couldn't find one, sorry. I may try a couple more mins of googling but it's a tough thing to query as it generates so many irrelevant hits. There's a mention of the effect at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8398/133219 FWIW.

Comment: @EdMorton No worries thanks so much. I'll take a look into it.

Comment: Sounds good. The issue is that the first time you run all your data gets loaded from disk into RAM so the 2nd time you run it's still there and so faster to access.